# Textview Not Accessible For Editing

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

I am having a little problem with my CommentsViewController that is being implemented using the IGListKit. I have created a cell that is being used to render the comments. Each cell contains a picture, the text, and a button that lets you flag inappropriate comments or reply to comments similar to how it is done in instagram.

This is the CollectionVIewCell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

protocol CommentCellDelegate: class {
    func optionsButtonTapped(cell: CommentCell)
    func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
class CommentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    weak var delegate: CommentCellDelegate? = nil
    override var reuseIdentifier : String {
        get {
            return "cellID"
        }
        set {
            // nothing, because only red is allowed
        }
    }
    var didTapOptionsButtonForCell: ((CommentCell) -> Void)?

    var comment: CommentGrabbed?{
        didSet{
            guard let comment = comment else{
                return
            }
          //  print("apples")
            // textLabel.text = comment.content
            //shawn was also here
            profileImageView.loadImage(urlString: comment.user.profilePic!)
            //  print(comment.user.username)
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment.user.username!, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)])
            attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: " " + (comment.content), attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))
            textView.attributedText = attributedText
        }
    }
    let textView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isEditable = false
        return textView
    }()
    lazy var profileImageView: CustomImageView = {
        let iv = CustomImageView()
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileTransition)))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return iv
    }()

    lazy var flagButton: UIButton = {
        let flagButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        flagButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-Info-64"), for: .normal)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(optionsButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return flagButton
    }()

    @objc func optionsButtonTapped (){
        didTapOptionsButtonForCell?(self)
    }

    @objc func onOptionsTapped() {
        delegate?.optionsButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
    @objc func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        delegate?.handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: tapGesture)
      //  print("Tapped image")
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(textView)
        addSubview(profileImageView)
        addSubview(flagButton)
        textView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: profileImageView.rightAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4, width: 0, height: 0)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 40/2
        flagButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 4, width: 40, height: 40)
        flagButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentCell.onOptionsTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now this controller has a delegate method that allows me to do some operation on click of the button. It allows me to present an alertcontroller which asks either reply or flag.
When I click reply I want the textfield to autoGenerate with @someUserName like how Instagram does and then I type some text, hit reply, and send the comment.

Below is my CommentSectionController
    import UIKit
    import IGListKit
    import Foundation
    import Firebase

```
protocol CommentsSectionDelegate: class {
    func CommentSectionUpdared(sectionController: CommentsSectionController)
}
class CommentsSectionController: ListSectionController,CommentCellDelegate {
    weak var delegate: CommentsSectionDelegate? = nil
    var comment: CommentGrabbed?
    let userProfileController = ProfileeViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    var eventKey: String?
    override init() {
        super.init()
        // supplementaryViewSource = self
        //sets the spacing between items in a specfic section controller
        inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    // MARK: IGListSectionController Overrides
    override func numberOfItems() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 50)
        let dummyCell = CommentCell(frame: frame)
        dummyCell.comment = comment
        dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        let targetSize =  CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: 55)
        let estimatedSize = dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize)
        let height = max(40+8+8, estimatedSize.height)
        return  CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: height)

    }

    override var minimumLineSpacing: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0.0
        }
        set {
            self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        }
    }

    override func cellForItem(at index: Int) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionContext?.dequeueReusableCell(of: CommentCell.self, for: self, at: index) as? CommentCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
        //  print(comment)
        cell.comment = comment
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
    override func didUpdate(to object: Any) {
        comment = object as? CommentGrabbed
    }
    override func didSelectItem(at index: Int){
    }

    func optionsButtonTapped(cell: CommentCell){
        print("like")

        let comment = self.comment
        _ = comment?.uid

        // 3
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        // 4
        if comment?.uid != User.current.uid {
            let flagAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Report as Inappropriate", style: .default) { _ in
                ChatService.flag(comment!)

                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "The post has been flagged.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
                self.viewController?.present(okAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let replyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Reply to Comment", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
                //do something here later to facilitate reply comment functionality
                print("Attempting to reply to user \(comment?.user.username) comment")

            })
            alertController.addAction(replyAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(flagAction)
        }else{
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete Comment", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                ChatService.deleteComment(comment!, (comment?.eventKey)!)
                let okAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Comment Has Been Deleted", preferredStyle: .alert)
                okAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
                self.viewController?.present(okAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.onItemDeleted()

            })
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            alertController.addAction(deleteAction)

        }
        self.viewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func onItemDeleted() {
        delegate?.CommentSectionUpdared(sectionController: self)
    }
    func handleProfileTransition(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        userProfileController.user = comment?.user
        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != comment?.uid{
                    self.viewController?.present(userProfileController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            //do nothing

        }


    }


}
```

Now my textView that I utilize for writing comments is in another file

```
import UIKit
protocol CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate {
    func handleSubmit(for comment: String?)
}

class CommentInputAccessoryView: UIView, UITextViewDelegate {
    var delegate: CommentInputAccessoryViewDelegate?
    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

   fileprivate let submitButton: UIButton = {
        let submitButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", for: .normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        submitButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        submitButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSubmit), for: .touchUpInside)
        //submitButton.isEnabled = false
        return submitButton
    }()

    lazy var commentTextView: CommentInputTextView = {
        let textView = CommentInputTextView()
       // textView.placeholder = "Add a comment"
        textView.delegate = self
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.backgroundColor = .white
        textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
       // textView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        return textView
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
       // backgroundColor = .red
        //1
        autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        addSubview(submitButton)
        submitButton.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, right:rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 12, width: 50, height: 0)
        addSubview(commentTextView)
        //3
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
                    commentTextView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: submitButton.leftAnchor, paddingTop: 8, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 8, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        }else{
            //fallback on earlier versions
        }

        setupLineSeparatorView()

    }
    // 2
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .zero
    }

    fileprivate func setupLineSeparatorView(){
        let lineSeparatorView = UIView()
        lineSeparatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230)
        addSubview(lineSeparatorView)
        lineSeparatorView.anchor(top:topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0.5)
    }

    @objc func handleSubmit(){
        guard let commentText = commentTextView.text else{
            return
        }
        delegate?.handleSubmit(for: commentText)
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextView) {
        let isCommentValid = commentTextView.text?.count ?? 0 > 0
        if isCommentValid {
            submitButton.isEnabled = true
        }else{
            submitButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
    func clearCommentTextField(){
        commentTextView.text = nil
        commentTextView.showPlaceholderLabel()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}
```

My question is how would I auto populate the textview from my commentsSectionController using IGListKit and keeping the same structure because I don't have access to it from my commentsSectionController

Comment: textView.isEditable = false ? you are setting it false it should be true in comment cell

Comment: well that is not exactly the issue I am facing